# JQuery Mobile Back Button properties

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery Mobile's back button, and I'm having trouble figuring out how it works.
If I have 3 pages: A, B, and C, where a link from page A takes you to page B, a link from page B takes to you to C, and pages B and C have these back buttons:

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a>
```

In this case, the back button works like your browser does, where if you had gone from A to B to C, using the back button would take you from page C to B to A.

But, if instead of the back button on page C, (Page B still using the first back button), using `data-rel="back"` and using something like this:

```
<a href="pageb.html">Back</a>
```

Then when you reach page B from page C, page B's `data-rel="back"` brings you to page C. (So you would go from A to B to C to B to C to B etc.)

Is there anyway to have the direct link to the page and still have it function like the first button?

Comment: The back button is working as designed. It always goes to the page you just came from. If you always want the back button to go to an exact page, just use a regular link button with the URL hard coded.

Comment: Is there a way to modify what part of the stack the back button looks at?